# Renumerar Columna agrupando

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server 2008 con la siguiente estructura:

- Referencia varchar(19)
- PackingList Integer

En ella tengo una serie de referencias alfanumericas a las que se les asignan unos numeros en el campo PackingList.

Referencia - PackingList

```
 1. REF001     - 18450
 2. REF001     - 18450
 3. REF001     - 18451
 4. REF001     - 18460
 5. REF004     - 9865
 6. REF004     - 9865
 7. REF004     - 9865
 8. REF004     - 9865
 9. REF004     - 9990
 10. REF004     - 9993
```

Lo que pretendo es obtener para cada referencia y número de PackingList un Id que empiece por el 1 en cada cambio de referencia y agrupe los mismos números de PackingList con el mismo Id dentro de la misma referencia.

El resultado que busco es:

```
 1. REF001     - 18450 - 1
 2. REF001     - 18450 - 1
 3. REF001     - 18451 - 2
 4. REF001     - 18460 - 3
 5. REF004     - 9865 - 1
 6. REF004     - 9865 - 1
 7. REF004     - 9865 - 1
 8. REF004     - 9865 - 1
 9. REF004     - 9990 - 2
 10. REF004     - 9993 - 3
```

He probado con `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION` pero no lo consigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno lo he conseguido con:

```
SELECT 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY REFERENCIA ORDER BY REFERENCIA, PACKINGLIST) AS Id
FROM TABLA
```